# Most efficient way to find index of matching values in two sorted arrays using C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, loops, matching

I currently have a solution but I feel it's not as efficient as it could be to this problem, so I want to see if there is a faster method to this.

I have two arrays (std::vectors for example). Both arrays contain only unique integer values that are sorted but are sparse in value, ie: 1,4,12,13... What I want to ask is there fast way I can find the INDEX to one of the arrays where the values are the same. For example, array1 has values 1,4,12,13 and array2 has values 2,12,14,16. The first matching value index is 1 in array2. The index into the array is what is important as I have other arrays that contain data that will use this index that "matches".

I am not confined to using arrays, maps are possible to. I am only comparing the two arrays once. They will not be reused again after the first matching pass. There can be small to large number of values (300,000+) in either array, but DO NOT always have the same number of values (that would make things much easier)

Worse case is a linear search O(N^2). Using map would get me better O(log N) but I would still have convert an array to into a map of value, index pairs.

What I currently have to not do any container type conversions is this. Loop over the smaller of the two arrays. Compare current element of small array (array1) with the current element of large array (array2). If array1 element value is larger than array2 element value, increment the index for array2 until is it no longer larger than array1 element value (while loop). Then, if array1 element value is smaller than array2 element, go to next loop iteration and begin again. Otherwise they must be equal and I have my index to either arrays of the matching value.

So in this loop, I am at best O(N) if all values have matches and at worse O(2N) if none match. So I am wondering if there is something faster out there? It's hard to know for sure how often the two arrays will match, but I would way I would lean more toward most of the arrays will mostly have matches than not.

I hope I explained the problem well enough and I appreciate any feedback or tips on improving this.

Code example:

```
std::vector<int> array1 = {4,6,12,34};
std::vector<int> array2 = {1,3,6,34,40};

for(unsigned int i=0, z=0; i < array1.size(); i++) 
{
    int value1 = array1[i];
    while(value1 > array2[z] && z < array2.size())
        z++;

    if (z >= array2.size())
        break; // reached end of array2

    if (value1 < array2[z])
        continue;

    // we have a match, i and z indices have same value

}
```

Result will be matching indexes for array1 = [1,3] and for array2= [2,3]

Comment: Added example code of current solution

Comment: I'm curious, what is the context where you need this algorithm?

Comment: I am using this with some association between two sets of data. In short, I have some arrays that contain IDs for an object. I then need gather data from a group of IDs in another array that may or may not be in the former.  by finding which index in the array a match exists, I can use that index to pull a variety of other data based on that index.

Comment: There is an implied constant factor in the definition of O(), so that 0(x) is equivalent to O(C*x) for any real number C. Basically constant factors like 2 are ignored in O-notation. 

I wasn't actually suggesting an explicit bounds check like that, but something like an adaptive algorithm that looks at head-2, -4, -8 etc when one of the arrays keeps having the smaller element. In that case you'd need only ~lg(N) checks when the arrays are largely disjoint as in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an implementation of this function using an algorithm that performs better with sparse distributions, than the trivial linear merge.

For distributions, that are similar<sup>†</sup>, it has O(n) complexity but ranges where the distributions are greatly different, it should perform below linear, approaching O(log n) in optimal cases. However, I wasn't able to prove that the worst case isn't better than O(n log n). On the other hand, I haven't been able to find that worst case either.

I templated it so that any type of ranges can be used, such as sub-ranges or raw arrays. Technically it works with non-random access iterators as well, but the complexity is much greater, so it's not recommended. I think it should be possible to modify the algorithm to fall back to linear search in that case, but I haven't bothered.

<sup>†</sup> By *similar* distribution, I mean that the pair of arrays have many *crossings*. By *crossing*, I mean a point where you would switch from one array to another if you were to merge the two arrays together in sorted order.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

// helper structure for the search
template<class Range, class Out>
struct search_data {
    // is any there clearer way to get iterator that might be either
    // a Range::const_iterator or const T*?
    using iterator = decltype(std::cbegin(std::declval<Range&>()));
    iterator curr;
    const iterator begin, end;
    Out out;
};

template<class Range, class Out>
auto init_search_data(const Range& range, Out out) {
    return search_data<Range, Out>{
        std::begin(range),
        std::begin(range),
        std::end(range),
        out,
    };
}

template<class Range, class Out1, class Out2>
void match_indices(const Range& in1, const Range& in2, Out1 out1, Out2 out2) {
    auto search_data1 = init_search_data(in1, out1);
    auto search_data2 = init_search_data(in2, out2);

    // initial order is arbitrary
    auto lesser = &search_data1;
    auto greater = &search_data2;

    // if either range is exhausted, we are finished
    while(lesser->curr != lesser->end
            && greater->curr != greater->end) {
        // difference of first values in each range
        auto delta = *greater->curr - *lesser->curr;

        if(!delta) { // matching value was found
            // store both results and increment the iterators
            *lesser->out++ = std::distance(lesser->begin, lesser->curr++);
            *greater->out++ = std::distance(greater->begin, greater->curr++);
            continue; // then start a new iteraton
        }

        if(delta < 0) { // set the order of ranges by their first value
            std::swap(lesser, greater);
            delta = -delta; // delta is always positive after this
        }

        // next crossing cannot be farther than the delta
        // this assumption has following pre-requisites: 
        // range is sorted, values are integers, values in the range are unique
        auto range_left = std::distance(lesser->curr, lesser->end);
        auto upper_limit =
            std::min(range_left, static_cast<decltype(range_left)>(delta));

        // exponential search for a sub range where the value at upper bound
        // is greater than target, and value at lower bound is lesser
        auto target = *greater->curr;
        auto lower = lesser->curr;
        auto upper = std::next(lower, upper_limit);
        for(int i = 1; i < upper_limit; i *= 2) {
            auto guess = std::next(lower, i);
            if(*guess >= target) {
                upper = guess;
                break;
            }
            lower = guess;
        }

        // skip all values in lesser,
        // that are less than the least value in greater
        lesser->curr = std::lower_bound(lower, upper, target);
    }
}

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> array1 = {4,6,12,34};
    std::vector<int> array2 = {1,3,6,34};

    std::vector<std::size_t> indices1;
    std::vector<std::size_t> indices2;

    match_indices(array1, array2,
                  std::back_inserter(indices1),
                  std::back_inserter(indices2));

    std::cout << "indices in array1: ";
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i : indices1)
        std::cout << i << ' ';

    std::cout << "\nindices in array2: ";
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i : indices2)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed example and I understand how this will help skip over greater amount of numbers rather than each one. This gives me some new ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Since the arrays are already sorted you can just use something very much like the merge step of mergesort. This just looks at the head element of each array, and discards the lower element (the next element becomes the head). Stop when you find a match (or when either array becomes exhausted, indicating no match).

This is O(n) and the fastest you can do for arbitrary distubtions. With certain clustered distributions a "skip ahead" approach could be used rather than always looking at the next element. This could result in better than O(n) running times for certain distributions. For example, given the arrays `1,2,3,4,5` and `10,11,12,13,14` an algorithm could determine there were no matches to be found in as few as one comparison (5 < 10).

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a closer look at the merge sort algorithm. I like the idea of your optimization to check the tail and head of two arrays to rule out no overlapping ranges. By your description of looking at the head element of each array and discarding if it's lower, is this not similar to what I am currently doing?

Comment: Yes, your algorithm (added after I answered) is the same thing. I was thrown off because you mentioned originally that it was O(N^2) which it isn't. BTW O(2N) doesn't make much sense. It is mathematically equivalent to O(N).

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned that a linear search for each element in another array could be N^2, I am not great at big O notion, but I thought looping over two arrays from beginning to end would be 2N, if a rough estimate. But I guess such thing does not exist? Yes, someone requested a code example after you posted so it all makes sense now. Thank you for confirming what you wrote to my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

What is the range of the stored numbers?

I mean, you say that the numbers are integers, sorted, and sparse (i.e. non-sequential), and that there may be more than 300,000 of them, but what is their actual range?

The reason that I ask is that, if there is a reasonably small upper limit, *u*, (say, *u*=500,000), the fastest and most expedient solution might be to just use the values as indices. Yes, you might be wasting memory, but is 4**u* really a lot of memory? This depends on your application and your target platform (i.e. if this is for a memory-constrained embedded system, its less likely to be a good idea than if you have a laptop with 32GiB RAM).

Of course, if the values are more-or-less evenly spread over 0-2^31-1, this crude idea isn't attractive, but maybe there are properties of the input values that you can exploit other simply than the range. You might be able to hand-write a fairly simple hash function.

Another thing worth considering is whether you actually need to be able to retrieve the index quickly or if it helps just be able to tell if the index exists in the other array quickly. Whether or not a value exists at a particular index requires only one bit, so you could have a bitmap of the range of the input values using 32x less memory (i.e. mask off 5 LSBs and use that as a bit position, then shift the remaining 27 bits 5 places right and use that as an array index).

Finally, a hybrid approach might be worth considering, where you decide how much memory you're prepared to use (say you decide 256KiB, which corresponds to 64Ki 4-byte integers) then use that as a lookup-table to into much smaller sub-problems. Say you have 300,000 values whose LSBs are pretty evenly distributed. Then you could use 16 LSBs as indices into a lookup-table of lists that are (on average) only 4 or 5 elements long, which you can then search by other means. A couple of year ago, I worked on some simulation software that had ~200,000,000 cells, each with a cell id; some utility functionality used a binary search to identify cells by id. We were able to speed it up significantly and non-intrusively with this strategy. Not a perfect solution, but a great improvement. (If the LSBs are not evenly distributed, maybe that's a property that you can exploit or maybe you can choose a range of bits that are, or do a bit of hashing.)

I guess the upshot is “consider some kind of hashing”, even the “identity hash” or simple masking/modulo with a little “your solution doesn't have to be perfectly general” on the side and some “your solution doesn't have to be perfectly space efficient” sauce on top.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas! I will not be able to enforce what range or upper value exists in the array. The size and values inside are determined at runtime by user interaction. The only thing I can know for sure are the ordering and uniqueness. I could convert one of the arrays into a non sparse version, almost like reversing the index/value relationship but I would still have to iterate over the entire array anyway to convert it, but the look up yes would be faster. If I was reusing the array again, I could see that being better, but I'm not. I'll look more into hashing as well. Thank you!